# Why doesn't this change the variable in my discord.py program?

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted to subtract from a variable in this code, but it won't subtract it.
I tried setting it global. What should I do?

```
rui=7
  

@commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def m(ctx):
    user = await client.fetch_user("MY ID HERE")
    mesa = ctx.author.id
    now = datetime.now()
    global rui
   
    await DMChannel.send(user,"-\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n#################\n# ROLL ÉRTESÍTŐ #\n#################\n\nA rollolás megkezdve a szobában az alábbi időben: {}\nRollolást megkezdte: {}".format(now,mesa))
    if mesa=="MY ID HERE":
        rui-=1
```

I tried requesting the variables with another command, but it says the original variable numbers (7).
What am I doing wrong?

If it is required I can send the full code in.
But I think it isn't needed. (Hopefully)

Thanks for every bit of help

Comment: On an unrelated note to your question, you might want to replace that `\n` spam with striong by integer multiplication: `'\n' * 10 + '#' * 12` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the user id you're passing is `int` type, not `str` because it won't work otherwise.

```py
rui=7

@commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
@client.command() # you don't have to use 'pass_context=True'
async def m(ctx):
    user = await client.fetch_user(1234567890) # your id as int
    mesa = ctx.author.id
    now = datetime.now()
    global rui
   
    await DMChannel.send(user,"-\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n#################\n# ROLL ÉRTESÍTŐ #\n#################\n\nA rollolás megkezdve a szobában az alábbi időben: {}\nRollolást megkezdte: {}".format(now,mesa))
    if mesa==1234567890: # your id as int
        rui-=1
```